# Stress Testing Your Mac For Optimal Performance?

Tags: hard-drive, memory, cpu

Stress testing maybe considered a useful way to determine if your Mac is performing at its optimal level of performance & may also be an indicator of faults of any components within your Mac.

What methods exist (ideally free if possible) to stress test to the max the following components:

- CPU
- Hard Disk
- Ram

Thereby identifying any problem(s) that may exist & if your Mac can handle them ?

Comment: A note to everyone considering this in 2019+: Most Macs these days use SSDs and they have a limited number of write cycles. So stress-testing an SSD for days on end, may not be a good idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CPU: purchase an app which can use up all the cores @ 100% and let it crank until your Mac is a pile of smoking plastic or the power goes out, which ever comes first. Rendering a large & complex animation with the Radiosity setting in Strata Studio Pro can do this for you.

HD: If you don't mind zapping the contents of the HD, run DiskUtility and then Erase the HD using the most stringent Security option available - a 7-pass write with zeros. It'll take days, but the disk heads will be in constant motion the whole time. With a MTBF usually measured in the millions of hours, it'll take more than a century to zap a perfectly constructed disk drive, given perfect electronics and no power dips/sags.

RAM: Take a look at [Memtest 4](http://www.memtestosx.org/) and run it endlessly.

In essence, I don't think I really, truly understand what you want to stress test here. To me, making sure these three components work optimally would mean:

- making sure the Mac has clean, filtered & conditioned power from a
  high-end battery-backup device;
- guaranteeing near-perfect environmental conditions (constant temperature,
  low humidity and low particulate levels)

You could also purchase 'Enterprise' grade hard drives.

All bets are off, though, should a gamma wave come through your neighborhood. In this case, you'd probably be more worried about keeping your skin from bursting into flames.

**2022 Edit:**

With the prevalence of SSDs over HDDs, the suggestion to erase the drive with a a stringent security regime is not recommended for SSDs.

See [this link at MacSales](https://eshop.macsales.com/blog/80464-how-to-check-your-mac-ssd-health/) for information about how to check the health of a SSD on macOS.

Comment: Found this article of interest which collaborates with your answer above http://www.mactricksandtips.com/2013/05/how-to-stress-test-your-mac-cpu-ram-and-disk.html

Answer (score 5):

There is a built-in hardware test designed by Apple.

With the introduction of Intel-based Macs, Apple has built the AHT utility right into your Mac.

Simply **hold down the D key while starting** up your Mac to boot into the Apple Hardware Test.

*I would not recommend using garden variety www not approved test programs. This would be the same as if you have a car with a speedometer marked 150 MPH would you actually drive it @155 MPH to find out if it holds up using non OEM tires?*

Comment: If a computer can break itself using unprivilleged user-space programs, there is something wrong with it. This is not a case of using non-OEM tires; this is a case of a self-driving car spontaneously combusting because someone told it to do a long-distance drive and it forgot to slow down.

Comment: Booting Apple Diagnostics is more complicated on Apple Silicon. See https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202731

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to test the CPU, fans and general heat management. It's an old Unix trick.

***Warning:*** *This can fry your system if your tempreture sensors are malfunctioning. Even if they are not, it will stress the system enough to affect operational lifetime if you repeat it to often. **Never run for more than 120 seconds! Never run unattended!***

1) Open Activity monitor and choose Window->CPU Monitor. This will provide a floating window showing a bar graph with one bar for each core. Your total number of cores they system sees both the hardware and virtual cores so your number of hardware cores is 1/2 the number of bars e.g. if you see 8 bars you have four hardware cores. This is the number to test.

I will term this window the "Core-window"

-2)because when the system becomes stressed it might not be able to switch the GUI. **If you wait to select the Killall-window unitl after the system cores are heavily taxed, you might not be able to stop the stress command before *it damages the system*.**

3) Watch the Core-window. One of the bars should rise to the top and stay there.  When the bar reaches the top, the core is maxed out. Hit return and activate the `killall yes` command.

4) Now that you have the system tested, you can max out all the cores. The virtual cores don't really count so count of the number of real cores. Now, repeat the step above ***exactly*** except that  in the Yes-window type '`yes > /dev/null &` then repeat for the number of real cores you have e.g. for 4 cores the command would be '`yes > /dev/null &  yes > /dev/null &  yes > /dev/null &  yes > /dev/null` but do not hit return.

5) Hit return and ***immediately*** click over to the Killall-window and prepare to hit return.

The time it takes the fans to come one and/or the system to lock up or crash will tell the type and scope of your problem.

A) Fans should come on about 10 seconds in. If they come on nearly immediately. You may have cooling issues e.g. dirty air intake

B)In all the systems I've done this on, the fans will reach maximum in under a 60 seconds. If they don't reach maximum within 90 seconds, you probably have bad fans.

C) If the system shuts down or locks up before the fans can be heard or before they max out, you have either bad fans, heat sink etc.

This is also a good way to stress a system to test how software behaves under system load. However, in those test you usually only max out about 25% of the cores.

(*There is a way to stress test drives as well manually but time precludes me detailing it. I'll add it later, time permitting.*)

Answer (score 0):

I would argue against 'stress-testing' for any reason. You're not looking for a leaky gasket or seeing if a valve blows.

Firstly, as pointed out, SSDs not hard drives are now the norm. You're not going to learn anything about its 'optimal performance' by filling it 100% full of data, one or more times. You might do nothing but shorten its life; though write-cycles are sufficiently high these days.

**RAM**
macOS will try to use as much RAM as it can, and will often 'fill' any spare memory with cached data. If your memory was reporting errors, your Mac wouldn't start.

**CPU**
Again, even if you use 100% of all your cores: what will that tell you? You might gain some insight into the performance under load; though arguably, you'd get more useful 'real-world' results just running whatever task you're actually planning on doing.